# How can multiple tiles be removed at once, or by group, from the Start Menu?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, tiles

The vast majority of the default Windows 10 start menu tiles (on the right side) are not needed. To remove them requires selecting each one and choosing `Unpin from Start`.

[image]
*(this is an image for reference)*

I have been researching a way to remove these tiles in bulk, or by group, but have been unsuccessful in finding a solution. I have searched for the shortcut location, like in previous versions of Windows, but was unable to find it.

How can multiple tiles be removed at once, or by group from the Start Menu?

Comment: I agree that it sucks that there's no way to select multiple tiles and apply bulk actions. (Wasn't there something like that in Windows 8 start screen though?) Just suck it up and remove them one by one. Anyway it's only a one-time thing, you're not doing it on a daily basis. No need to wait for a solution. Just do it and get on with life.

Comment: Wish it had been a one-time thing. In this particular case, I had several PCs to configure. So, it was a painful process to go thru. Still sucked, nonetheless.

Comment: I see, I understand your pain. There was no Group Policy or some other network administration method to control what tiles would appear in all the PCs? Or these are just PCs completely independent from each other and not belonging to an organizational network? Have you considered cloning a fully-set-up Windows installation (without key) to all the PCs? All you need to do is slap in the individual PC's product key after the copy is complete and the PC booted. *(Just throwing ideas out here, but I understand your pain.)*

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but this project has now been completed. Of course, after it was complete, I found instructions to [Customize Windows 10 Start with Group Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/customize-windows-10-start-screens-by-using-group-policy) in the subsequent question [How to remove all the tiles in the Windows 10 start menu?](http://superuser.com/q/1068382/97028). It was what I was looking for, but a little too late. :-)

Comment: Great, although I was looking at edition comparisons and it looked like only Enterprise editions allowed the mass customization of the tiles in Start menu via group policies. PS: In fact, the article starts with *"In Windows 10 Enterprise and Windows 10 Education..."*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all the tiles in the Windows 10 start menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/1068382/how-to-remove-all-the-tiles-in-the-windows-10-start-menu)